# how to Override Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current File in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, framework, magento-framework

**Problem**

I want to add an attribute to current link in Magento 2 Customer Dashboard i Checked `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current`, there in `Line 119` All the Link Having an Li have a function `$this->getAttributesHtml()` by which all none current link can assigned an HTML attribute passed from XML

Now the current link hasn't assigned `$this->getAttributesHtml()`  that why the attribute passed through XML is Not assigned to current link

I tried to Override Current Class as Follows

> etc\frontend\di.xml

```
 <preference 
    for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" 
    type="Vendor\Module\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" />
```

> Vendor\Module\View\Element\Html\Link\Current

Changed this Condition

```
    if ($this->isCurrent()) {
        $html = '<li class="nav item current">';
        $html .= '<strong'>'
            . $this->escapeHtml(__($this->getLabel()))
            . '</strong>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
```

To

```
    if ($this->isCurrent()) {
        $html = '<li class="nav item current">';
        $html .= '<strong '.$this->getAttributesHtml() .'>'
            . $this->escapeHtml(__($this->getLabel()))
            . '</strong>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
```

If I make a change in Core File I works Fine But in Overridden Class
Its Now Working

Need Help

Comment: is your module enabled? and did you clean the cache?

Comment: Yes i Have Clean cache

Comment: and did you verify that your module is enabled?

Comment: yes module is enable and all other functionalities are working fine only thi file is not overriding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to overwrite links on the customer account page:

[image: menu on the customer account page]

you should make a preference for the `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLink` class, not for it's parent.

Use this preference in `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLink" type="Vendor\Model\Block\CurrentLink" />
```

Extend a real class inside:

```
class CurrentLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLink
```

and overwrite a protected method `_toHtml` per your needs:

```
/**
 * Render block HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $highlight = '';

    if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
        $highlight = ' current';
    }

    if ($this->isCurrent()) {
        $html = '<li class="nav item current">';
        $html .= '<strong '.$this->getAttributesHtml() .'>'
            . $this->escapeHtml(__($this->getLabel()))
            . '</strong>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    } else {
        $html = '<li class="nav item' . $highlight . '"><a href="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getHref()) . '"';
        $html .= $this->getTitle()
            ? ' title="' . $this->escapeHtml(__($this->getTitle())) . '"'
            : '';
        $html .= $this->getAttributesHtml() . '>';

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '<strong>';
        }

        $html .= $this->escapeHtml(__($this->getLabel()));

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '</strong>';
        }

        $html .= '</a></li>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Do not forget to clean cache and run `setup:di:compile`.

If you want to add the `id` for the current link, just change this line (inside the `if ($this->isCurrent())` condition body):

```
$html = '<li class="nav item current">';
```

to the:

```
$html = '<li class="nav item current" id="current-link">';
```

clean cache and see updated result on the page:

[image: current link with id attribute on the page]

Comment: how i can add `id` attribute on current link using 'SortLink' class ?

Comment: @WaqarAli same way as you doing it before but with another class. I've update my answer.

Comment: @WaqarAli I've update my answer added with id attribute for the current link.

Comment: Thank You Sir Its Working Great